# Show/Hide SubMenu issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple menu system on my website. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a41xkr9z/2/

My Problem: when I click 'Projects' it displays the submenu. However, if you click 'Projects' **again**, it hides the menu. How do I prevent this?

Javascript:

```
$('#menu-primary-menu>li>a').click(function() {
  $(this).parents("ul").find("li>ul").not($(this).next()).hide();
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Comment: how are you expecting the functionality to work exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#menu-primary-menu>li>a').click(function() {
  $(this).parents("ul").find("li>ul").not($(this).next()).hide();
 $(this).next().fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Thanks

Comment: Approved answer too - had to wait a bit there :)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Change `$(this).next().toggle();` to `$(this).next().show();`.

Comment: The only issue here is: http://jsfiddle.net/a41xkr9z/6/ See what happens if you click `More Projects` then `Projects`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `.toggle()` the function change the status of the element hidden/shown.

Use `.show()` or `.hide()` if you only want one action.